# MYSQL How to get unique values from two tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get unique Value from two tables but the problem is the data in 'd.feedback' is displaying all  of the data in the column feedback from daily_report table.

This is the code that I use. So what do you think I should do? Distinct `fullname` and `feedback`? or is there another alternative?

```
 SET @row := 0;
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname) as 'Regular Users', d.feedback
  FROM daily_report d
   INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.id
```

**Here is the First Table**

```
| id | firstname |
| -- | ----------|
| 1  | Christian |
| 2  | Levi      |
| 3  | Brian     |
```

**Here is the Second Table**

```
| userid| feedback  | id     |
| --    | ----------|--------|
| 1     | Thanks    |    1   |
| 2     | Arigato   |    1   |
| 3     | Sure      |    2   |
| 4     | Thank you |    2   |
| 5     | Thank you |    2   |
| 6     | Thank you |    2   |
```

**Desired output**

| Regular User | feedback |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Christian | Thanks |
| 2 Christian | Arigato |
| 3 Levi | Sure |
| 4 Levi | Thank you |

**And Here is my problem**

[image]

I''m am getting duplicate value like Number 2 and 4

Comment: You have a typo in your `ON` condition. You want `INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.userid`. Please see [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itTNUHADk16CyHFGCsmrGm/0).

Comment: sorry about that i made a mistake in typing please take a look again

Comment: Look at the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itTNUHADk16CyHFGCsmrGm/0). Your query gives precisely your desired output.

Comment: sorry about that again what i mean is to make the feedback distinct

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an actual example of your desired output? Surely you don't want to build in the knowledge that `Arigato` == `Thanks`?  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: i show you the return query of my command

Comment: Try adding `GROUP BY ui.userid,ui.firstname,d.feedback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want

````
SELECT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname) as 'Regular Users', 
       d.feedback
  FROM (select distinct feedback, userid from daily_report) d INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.userid;```
````

Answer (score 1):

This query allows DISTINCT to do its job.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ui.firstname as 'Regular Users', 
       d.feedback
  FROM daily_report d INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.userid;
```

When you do `DISTINCT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname) as 'Regular Users'` you make every value of `Regular Users` different from the others, which defeats DISTINCT.